# No InputStream specified when use spring-mvc-test andDo() method

Tags: inputstream, mockmvc, spring-mvc-test

recently when i do my work using spring-mvc-test-framework,code like this:

```
this.mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/manage/bill/detail/{id}","5507c2240cf2bc43ba2367bd").accept(MediaType.ALL)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk()).andDo(MockMvcRestDocumentation.document("index"));
```

then i got this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No InputStream specified
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copy(FileCopyUtils.java:106)
at   org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(FileCopyUtils.java:156)
at org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcOperationRequestFactory.createOperationRequest(MockMvcOperationRequestFactory.java:83)
at       org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationResultHandler.handle(RestDocumentationResultHandler.java:93)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andDo(MockMvc.java:155)
```

I searched and find no answers.
can anybody tell me why this happens?

Now I got another solution.

actually I use Spring MVC test example in its offical reference http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html5/#getting-started-build-configuration-maven-packaging and use the setUp() method like this:

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();
```

the aim is to document api 。Now the another solution is I use apply() method and then problem solved.

first,i changed to :

```
this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .apply(MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation)).build();
```

then solved the version problem like this:
[spring-restdocs is not recognizing apply()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052007/spring-restdocs-is-not-recognizing-apply)

All my code below:

```
package com.dream.bwm.test.test;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation;
import org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.MockMvcRestDocumentation;
import org.springframework.restdocs.mockmvc.RestDocumentationRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:spring/root-context.xml", "classpath:spring/app-context.xml" })
public class DocsGenerator {

    public static String outputDir = "D:\\workspace-bwme\\pro-root\\bwme-backend\\target\\generated-snippets";

    @Rule
    public final RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation(outputDir);

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // this.mockMvc =
        // MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context).build();

        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.context)
                .apply(MockMvcRestDocumentation.documentationConfiguration(this.restDocumentation)).build();

    }

    // @Test
    public void printOnConsole() throws Exception {

        this.mockMvc
                .perform(
                        MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/manage/bill/detail/{id}", "5507c2240cf2bc43ba2367bd").accept(
                                MediaType.ALL_VALUE)).andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());// MockMvcRestDocumentation.document("index")
    }

    @Test
    public void writeToDocument() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc
                .perform(
                        RestDocumentationRequestBuilders.get("/manage/bill/detail/{id}", "5507c2240cf2bc43ba2367bd")
                                .accept(MediaType.ALL)).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andDo(MockMvcRestDocumentation.document("index"));

    }
}
```

hope this can give you some help if someone encounters such questions.

Comment: Don't add code as comments, modify your initial question.

Comment: sorry,first time post question on the platform.thx for you advice